# Unexpected (automatic) navigation with SwiftUI on watchOS

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a simple *watchOS 6.2.8* SwiftUI application in which I present a list of messages to the user.

These messages are modelled as classes and have a title, body and category name. I also have a Category object which is a view on these messages that only shows a specific category name.

> I specifically mention *watchOS 6.2.8* because it seems SwiftUI behaves a bit different there than on other platforms.

```
class Message: Identifiable {
    let identifier: String
    let date: Date
    let title: String
    let body: String
    let category: String
    
    var id: String {
        identifier
    }

    init(identifier: String, date: Date, title: String, body: String, category: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.date = date
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        self.category = category
    }
}

class Category: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let name: String
    @Published var messages: [Message] = []
    
    var id: String {
        name
    }

    init(name: String, messages: [Message] = []) {
        self.name = name
        self.messages = messages
    }
}
```

Category itself is an `@ObservableObject` and publishes `messages`, so that when a category gets updated (like in the background), the view that is displaying the category message list will also update. (This works great)

To store these messages I have a simple `MessageStore`, which is an `@ObservableObject` that looks like this:

```
class MessageStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var messages: [Message] = []
    @Published var categories: [Category] = []

    static let sharedInstance = MessageStore()

    func insert(message: Message) throws { ... mutage messages and categories ... }
    func delete(message: Message) throws { ... mutage messages and categories ... }
}
```

(For simplicity I use a singleton, because there are problems with environment objects not being passed properly on watchOS)

The story keeps `messages` and `categories` in sync. When a new *Message* is added that has a category name set, it will also create or update a `Category` object in the `categories` list.

In my main view I present two things:

- An *All Messages* `NavigationLink` that goes to a view to display all messages
- For each *Category* I display a `NavigationLink` that goes to a view to display messages just in that specific category.

[image]

This all works, amazingly. But there is one really odd thing happening that I do not understand. (First SwiftUI project)

When I go into the *All Messages* list and delete all messages containing to a specific category, something unexpected happen when I *navigate back to the main view*.

First I observe that the category is properly removed from the list.

**But then, the main view *automatically* quickly navigates to the All Messages list and then back.**

The last part is driving me .. crazy .. I don't understand why this is happening. From a data perspective everyting looks good - the messages have been deleted and the category too. The final UI state, after the automagical navigation, also looks good - the message count for All Messages is correct and the category with now zero messages is not shown in the list anymore.

Here is the code for the main `ContentView` and also for the `AllMessagesView`. If helpful I can post the complete code here of course.

```
struct AllMessagesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var messageStore = MessageStore.sharedInstance

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if messageStore.messages.count == 0 {
            Text("No messages").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .navigationBarTitle("All Messages")
        } else {
            List {
                ForEach(messageStore.messages) { message in
                    MessageCellView(message: message)
                }.onDelete(perform: deleteMessages)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("All Messages")
        }
    }

    func deleteMessages(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            do {
                try messageStore.delete(message: messageStore.messages[index])
            } catch {
                NSLog("Failed to delete message: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}

//

struct CategoryMessagesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var messageStore = MessageStore.sharedInstance

    @ObservedObject var category: Category

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if category.messages.count == 0 {
                Text("No messages in category “\(category.name)”").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(category.messages) { message in
                        MessageCellView(message: message)
                    }.onDelete(perform: deleteMessages)
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(category.name)
    }

    func deleteMessages(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            do {
                try messageStore.delete(message: category.messages[index])
            } catch {
                NSLog("Cannot delete message: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var messageStore = MessageStore.sharedInstance

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                NavigationLink(destination: AllMessagesView()) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "tray.2")
                        Text("All Messages")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(messageStore.messages.count)")
                            .font(messageCountFont())
                            .bold()
                            .layoutPriority(1)
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Section {
                Group {
                    if messageStore.categories.count > 0 {
                        Section {
                            ForEach(messageStore.categories) { category in
                                NavigationLink(destination: CategoryMessagesView(category: category)) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(systemName: "tray") // .foregroundColor(.green)
                                        Text("\(category.name)").lineLimit(1).truncationMode(.tail)
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text("\(category.messages.count)")
                                            .font(self.messageCountFont())
                                            .bold()
                                            .layoutPriority(1)
                                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // TODO This is pretty inefficient
    func messageCountFont() -> Font {
        let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        return Font(font.withSize(font.pointSize * 0.75))
    }
}
```

Apologies, I know this is a lot of code, but I feel I need to give enough context and visibility to show what is going on here.

Full project at https://github.com/st3fan/LearningSwiftUI/tree/master/MasterDetail - I don't think more code is relevant, but if it is, let me know and I'll move it into the question here.

Comment: Is there a reason `Message` is a class? In my experience, SwiftUI data objects work better as structs unless you have a need for reference semantics, which it doesn't seem that you do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in updated `ForEach` which result in recreating `List` and thus breaks link. This looks like SwiftUI defect, so worth submitting feedback to Apple.

The tested workaround is to move All Messages navigation link out of list (looks a bit different but might be appropriate). Tested with Xcode 12 / watchOS 7.0

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var messageStore = MessageStore.sharedInstance

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: AllMessagesView()) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "tray.2")
                    Text("All Messages")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(messageStore.messages.count)")
                        .font(messageCountFont())
                        .bold()
                        .layoutPriority(1)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }
            }
            List {
                ForEach(messageStore.categories) { category in
                    NavigationLink(destination: CategoryMessagesView(category: category)) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "tray") // .foregroundColor(.green)
                            Text("\(category.name)").lineLimit(1).truncationMode(.tail)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(category.messages.count)")
                                .font(self.messageCountFont())
                                .bold()
                                .layoutPriority(1)
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ... other code
```

Comment: Thank you this is an interesting approach. I sort of ended up with this myself too, where I don't use a `List` but instead `ScrollView` - the UI is a bit different then, but the odd behaviour goes away.